# converting dec to hex

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm trying to convert dec to hex. Maximum number is 65535 and when I want to convert 5 digit number everything is just fine but when I write for example 3 digits and then press enter it doesn't work. What is wrong? I belive it has to do something with that enter but I don't know what exactly.

```
 input:         mov    ah,01h 
                int    21h
                call   chck
                mov    ah,00h
                push   numbers
                mov    numbers,ax                
                inc    digit
                CMP    digit,5
                JZ     petl
                loop   input
petl:           mov    ax,numbers
                pop    numbers 
                sub    al,30h
                cmp    digit2,0
                jz     cont              
                mov    cx,digit2
multip:         mul    000ah
                loop   multip             
cont:           add    bx,ax 
                jb     error                     
                mov    dx,digit
                inc    digit2  
                cmp    digit2,dx
                jz     conv        
                jmp    petl 
chck:           cmp    al,13
                 jz     petl
                cmp    al,30h
                jb     error
                cmp    al,39h
                jg     error
                ret
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. Also, comment your code if you want other people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a POP that is not matched by a PUSH! You don't need this POP.

```
czek:           pop numbers
```

**EDIT**
You need to exchange these instructions! The first time NUMBERS contains garbage.

```
push   numbers
mov    numbers,ax
```

At the label PETL: you also need to exchange such instructions.

```
petl:   mov    ax,numbers
        pop    numbers
```

Comment: Right, thanks. I don't know why I put it there... Anyway I fixed it and it still doesn't work as it should

Comment: See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I made it work. After first POP it didn't take next digit but instead hex number ED. I made additional pop and now it works just fine.
But what is this ED? It was there no matter what number I input.

For example if I would input 451. I type 4 push it to the stack, type 5 push it and then type 1. Now when I POP i get this EB, 2nd POP is 5 and 3rd 4.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid X86 instruction. Perhaps you meant `imul ax,10`.

```
mul    000ah
```

Did you clear variable DIGIT and register BX beforehand ?

Did you set CX=5 beforehand ? Furthermore can you see the redundancy with this code ?

```
CMP    digit,5
JZ     petl
loop   input
```

This code does not eliminate values in the range 128-255! You mix unsigned `jb` with signed `jg`.

```
            cmp    al,30h
            jb     error
            cmp    al,39h
            jg     error
```

Your program doesn't deal with the possibility of an empty input. It would crash!